# Updating the MQ Resource Adapter in JBoss

Tags: jboss, jms, ibm-mq, resource-adapter

I just want to double-check what the exact steps are for updating the MQ Resource Adapter in JBoss.

I can find a lot of guides on how to deploy it and configure it, but none on updating it.

I have got JBoss 6.3 and MQ RA 7.5.0.5 (need to update to RA 7.5.0.9). Is it just a matter of stopping the application server, removing wmq.jmsra.rar from the deployment directory, copying the new wmq.jmsra.rar version in there and starting up JBoss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from 7.5.0.5 to 7.5.0.9 is a very small update so I wouldn't expect there would be any configuration updates required. The process you outlined (i.e. stop JBoss, update rar, start JBoss) should be perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Justin. Appreciate your prompt reply.